# JSON parse error - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position XXX when I try to upload Excel Sheet using Angular+REST

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework

I am trying my hands on File Upload using Django REST and Angular.
Following is the angular directory structure:

```
app
|-----uploadcomponent
           |-----uploadcomponent.module.ts
           |-----uploadcomponent.html
|-----app.module.ts
|-----app.component.ts
|-----app.service.ts
```

uploadcomponent.htl:

```html
           <div>
                <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

                    <input type="file" name="profile"  enctype="multipart/form-data" accept=".xlsm,application/msexcel" (change)="onChange($event)" />
                    <button type="submit">Upload Template</button>
                    <button id="delete_button" class="delete_button" type="reset"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button> 
                  </form>           
            </div>
```

uploadcomponent.ts:

```js
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    ....
    export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {
        form: FormGroup;
        constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private uploadService: AppService) {}
        ngOnInit() {  
            this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
               profile: ['']
            });
        }

        onChange(event) {
            if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
              const file = event.target.files[0];

              this.form.get('profile').setValue(file);
              console.log(this.form.get('profile').value)
            }
        }

        onSubmit() {
           const formData = new FormData();
           formData.append('file', this.form.get('profile').value);

           this.uploadService.upload(formData).subscribe(
             (res) => {
               this.response = res;

               console.log(res);

             },
             (err) => {  
               console.log(err);
             });
         }
    }
```

app.service.ts:

```js
    upload(formData) {
        const endpoint = this.service_url+'upload/';
        return this.http.post(endpoint, formData, httpOptions);
    }
```

Now in the backend I am using Django Rest Framework:
Following are the required files of code:
models.py:

```py
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
    from django.db import models
    from django.db import connection
    from django_mysql.models import JSONField, Model
    import uuid
    import os


    def change_filename(instance, filename):
        extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
        file_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        uuid_name = uuid.uuid4()
        return file_name+"_"+str(uuid_name)+"."+extension

    class UploadTemplate (Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False, upload_to=change_filename)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.file.name)
```

views.py:

```py
    class UploadView(APIView):
        serializer_class = UploadSerializer
        parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)

        def get_queryset(self):
            queryset = UploadTemplate.objects.all()
            return queryset

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            file_serializer = UploadSerializer(data=request.data)
            status = None
            message = None
            if file_serializer.is_valid():
                file_serializer.save()
                status = "Success"
                message = "Success"
            else:
                status = "Failure"
                message = "Failure!"
            content = {'status': status, 'message': message}
            return Response(content)
```

serializers.py:

```py
    from uploadtemplate.models import UploadTemplate
    from rest_framework import serializers

    class UploadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = UploadTemplate
            fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py:

```py
    router.register(r'uploadtemplate', uploadtemplateviews.UploadTemplateView, base_name='UploadTemplate')
    urlpatterns = [
        ....
        url(r'upload/', uploadtemplateviews.UploadTemplateView.as_view()),
    ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

    if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also I have made required changes in settings.py.
Now when I upload an excel sheet (.xlsm extension) through UI, I get the following error:

```
JSON parse error - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 213: invalid continuation byte
```

Now, when I try to read the same excel file using `pandas`, I can see that few of the column values are `NaN` and I doubt this might be the reason for decoding.
Can someone please help me out on how to handle this in Angular/Rest so that my file uploads successfully.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer for this...
In `views.py` I had to change the parser to:
`parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]`

So my views.py now looks like:

```
class UploadView(APIView):
        serializer_class = UploadSerializer
        parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]         <<<<< Changes are here

        def get_queryset(self):
            queryset = UploadTemplate.objects.all()
            return queryset

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            file_serializer = UploadSerializer(data=request.data)
            status = None
            message = None
            if file_serializer.is_valid():
                file_serializer.save()
                status = "Success"
                message = "Success"
            else:
                status = "Failure"
                message = "Failure!"
            content = {'status': status, 'message': message}
            return Response(content)
```

Also, the http request was sending `Content-Type` as `application/json` by default.
Had to change it. So my apps.service.ts looked as following:

```
upload(formData) {
        const endpoint = this.service_url+'upload/';
        const httpOptions = headers: new HttpHeaders({    <<<< Changes are here
            'Authorization': 'token xxxxxxx'})
        };
        return this.http.post(endpoint, formData, httpOptions);
    }
```

Thank You!